# How to stop MPAndroidChart chart.centerViewToAnimated( currentXVisible + 60, currentY, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT, 15000 );

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am wanting to animate my drawn data, with controls much like a media player: Play, Stop, fast forward, etc....over my  Xaxis - AKA over time....

I have tried creating my own Runnable both on and off the UI thread with no success with making calls to increment the xvalue by small amounts, etc .... but does not move the view port windows.

I can get my chart to animate  using chart.centerViewToAnimated, but want to be able to "stop" this animation ... I cannot see how to do this even with a ViewPortHandler...

Any ideas??

Comment: chart.getAnimation() only returns nul, so cannot call chart.getAnimation().cancel();

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the animation started by `chart.centerViewToAnimated(...)` cannot be cancelled. So you need to make small steps. If the steps are small enough, you can use `chart.centerViewTo(...)` (without animation).

I have implemented this with 50ms interval and it looks decent.